# python scope issue with anonymous lambda in metaclass

Tags: python, scope, metaclass

I am using a metaclass to define read-only properties (accessor methods) for a class, by adding a property with only a getter (a lambda) for each field declared by the class.  I am finding different behavior depending on where I define the lambda.  It works if I define the getter lambda in an external function that is called by the `__new__` method of the metaclass, and not if I define the lambda in directly in the `__new__` method of the metaclass.

```
def _getter(key):
    meth =  lambda self : self.__dict__[key]
    print "_getter: created lambda %s for key %s" % (meth, key)
    return meth


class ReadOnlyAccessors(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsName, bases, dict):

        for fname in dict.get('_fields',[]):
            key = "_%s" % fname

            # the way that works
            dict[fname] = property(_getter(key)) 

            # the way that doesn't
            # meth = lambda self : self.__dict__[key]
            # print "ReadOnlyAccessors.__new__: created lambda %s for key %s" % (meth, key)
            # dict[fname] = property(meth)

        return type.__new__(cls, clsName, bases, dict)


class ROThingy(object):
    __metaclass__ = ReadOnlyAccessors

    _fields = ("name", "number")

    def __init__(self, **initializers):
        for fname in self._fields:
            self.__dict__[ "_%s" % fname ] = initializers.get(fname, None)
        print self.__dict__


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rot = ROThingy(name="Fred", number=100)
    print "name = %s\nnumber = %d\n" % (rot.name, rot.number)
```

As currently written, execution looks like this:

```
[slass@zax src]$ python ReadOnlyAccessors.py
_getter: created lambda <function <lambda> at 0x7f652a4d88c0> for key _name
_getter: created lambda <function <lambda> at 0x7f652a4d8a28> for key _number
{'_number': 100, '_name': 'Fred'}
name = Fred
number = 100
```

Commenting out the line that follows "the way that works" and uncommenting the three lines following "the way that doesn't" produces this:

```
    [slass@zax src]$ python ReadOnlyAccessors.py
    ReadOnlyAccessors.__new__: created lambda <function <lambda> at 0x7f40f5db1938> for key _name
    ReadOnlyAccessors.__new__: created lambda <function <lambda> at 0x7f40f5db1aa0> for key _number
    {'_number': 100, '_name': 'Fred'}
    name = 100
    number = 100
```

Note that even though the `rot.__dict__` shows that `_name` is `'Fred'`, the value returned by the `name` Property is `100`.

Clearly I'm not understanding something about the scope in which I'm creating the lambdas.

I've been reading Guido's document about metaclass for accessors here:
https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#cooperation
as well as the Python docs for the Python Data Model and this 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/307969-generating-getset-methods-using-a-metaclass/
recipe for creating accessors using a metaclass,
and finally everything on StackOverflow that I can find, but I'm just not getting it.

Thank you.

-Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has to do with [scope](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). When you define `meth` with

```
meth = lambda self : self.__dict__[key]
```

the `key` variable is not a variable in `meth`'s local scope. So when the `meth` function is called, `key` must be searched for in the enclosing scope. (See the [LEGB rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).) It finds it in the scope of the `__new__` method. However, by the time `meth` gets called, the value of `key` is not necessarily the value of `key` when `meth` was defined. Rather the value of `key` is *the last value* it was assigned to due to the `for-loop`. It happens to always be `'_number'`. So no matter what `meth` you call, the value of `self.__dict__['_number']` is being returned.

You can see that this is what is happening by defining `meth` this way inside `__new__`:

```
    for fname in dict.get('_fields',[]):
        key = "_%s" % fname

        def meth(self):
            print(key) # See what `meth` believes `key` is
            return self.__dict__[key]
```

yields

```
_number    # key is always `_number`
_number
name = 100
number = 100
```

---

The reason why `_getter` works is because `key` gets passed to `_getter`. So when `meth` gets called, it finds the value of `key` in `_getter`'s scope, where `key` retains the value it got when `_getter` was called.

---

If you want to use a lambda instead of `_getter`, you can do so by using a default value for `key`:

```
meth = lambda self, key=key: self.__dict__[key]
```

Now, inside `meth`, `key` is a *local* variable. So when `meth` is called, the value of `key` will be the value of `key` in the local scope. The default value is bound to the function at *definition-time*, so the right value is being bound to each `meth` lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another manifestation of the "late-binding" of python closures and has nothing to do with metaclasses ;-) -- Although maybe the metaclass in play makes the actual issue harder to see...  consider:

```
funcs = [lambda: x for x in range(30)]
print funcs[0]()  # 29!
```

The reason is that the lambda function looks up the value from the closure *when it is called*, not when it was created.  In this case, even though `i` was `0` when the first function was created, when it gets called, `i` has a value of `29`.

Now in your case, you've got the same thing happening, only with the variable `key`.  One simple way to fix it is to bind the value as a keyword argument to the function (as those get evaluated at creation time):

```
funcs = [lambda _x=x: _x for x in range(30)]
```

or, in your case:

```
meth = lambda self, _key: self.__dict__[_key]
```

Answer (score 0):

key word is dynamic scope.

it's very easy to step into the trap here.

to make the problem easier, forget about OO, just try to think about following code:

```
arr = []
for i in range(5):
    arr.append(lambda: i)

for lmb in arr:
    print lmb()
```

and this code:

```
def lmb_gen(val):
    return lambda: val

arr = []
for i in range(5):
    arr.append(lmb_gen(i))

for lmb in arr:
    print lmb()
```

easy answer is the i in lambda is binded to the i in the for loop, which is keep changing before the lambda get called. that's why 5 4's get printed.

while, in the second examples, the val in lambda is binded to the parameter val, which varies every time when the lmb_gen get called. therefore, in another word, the environment is different.

the rule is, when a variable do not defined in a function, the variable is actually binded to the first one of the "outer" environments.

this phenomenon does not only happen in lambda's case, but happen in named functions' case.